# I want the program to display a message if the user input is not in the list and continue asking for another input! What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, arrays, list, for-loop, if-statement

Hope everyone is doing good. I just joined this platform. So, I have just started learning python about a week or so from YouTube. This is my first program please tell me what am I doing wrong here. I want the program to display message if the user input is not in the list and continue asking for another input!
Thank you.

```
numbers = [7,3,13,6,8,5,1,2,4,15,9,10,12,14,11]
new_list = []
while True:
    num = int(input("Enter any number from the list 'numbers': "))
    for i in numbers:
        if i < num:
            new_list.append(i)
            new_list.sort()
        elif num != i:
            print("Number doesn't exist in the list 'numbers'")
        break
    print(new_list)
```

Comment: Why do you need to make a sorted list each time? If the goal is to just check "*if the user input is not in the list*", why not do `if num in numbers`?

Comment: @GinoMempin Sir, can you please write it in code what you mean. Actually this problem is from a python excersise https://www.practicepython.org/solution/2014/02/26/03-list-less-than-ten-solutions.html and I was trying my own variation for fun.

Comment: Your code tries to produce a list with numbers from the list which are less than entered number by the user. It also prints if each number in the list which is bigger than the entered number. So the code, and definition of the code by you is totally different.

Comment: @aza Sir Sir can you modify my code only and tell me to print the message "Number doesn't exist in the list 'numbers'" and ask for another input if the input by user is not in the numbers = [7,3,13,6,8,5,1,2,4,15,9,10,12,14,11].

Comment: I do not have any knowledge about python but you can check my answer below. It might be helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

This code would do the work:

```
numbers = [7,3,13,6,8,5,1,2,4,15,9,10,12,14,11]
not_in_list = True
while not_in_list:
    number = int(input("Enter any number from the list 'numbers': "))
    if number in numbers:
        not_in_list = False
```

Comment: Sir can you use my code only and tell me how should I modify it to print the message "Number doesn't exist in the list 'numbers'" and ask for another input if the input by user is not in the numbers = [7,3,13,6,8,5,1,2,4,15,9,10,12,14,11]. Thanks.

Comment: you can check whether a value is in a list or not using "in" as I did that in line 5. 
if the "if statement" does not evaluate, line 6 would not work, and while loop would iterate once more and shows the message again.

Answer (score 0):

the quesion you asked is not exactly what you are  trying in your code. I can't undestand the idea behind creating new list. but in general you can use nested functions to write your code and continuously asking user to input data if the previous input is not what you want.
remember in such cases that you are looking for number in a list that contains only numbers, you should control user input type. for instance show warning if the input is string.

```
numbers = [7,3,13,6,8,5,1,2,4,15,9,10,12,14,11]
def ask_number():
    num = int(input("Enter any number from the list 'numbers': "))
    check_number(num)

def check_number(num):
    if num not in numbers:
        print("Number does not exist in the list")
        ask_number()
    else:
        print(f"found {num} in list")

ask_number()
```